# AJAX code for implementing PUT in HTML Form does not appear to be executing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

My website consumes an API that I have written. Currently I have written a page that consumes a GET, and a page that consumes a POST. I am having a lot of trouble with PUT however.

I currently have two functions with the same name, but different arguments. I have ChangeOneEmu(), and ChangeOneEmu(EmuItem model), the second being the "put" method.

I learned through a previous question of mine that I cannot get HTTP forms, or even the  tag, to send things via a PUT method since HTTP doesn't support PUT. So I've been attempting to use AJAX to send it via PUT and it also doesn't appear to be working.

Essentially, what is happening as of right now is that my function with **no** arguments calls the view, which loads the View correctly-I can input data just fine. When I press the "submit" button however, it doesn't go to my PUT method (the action that takes in the model argument). It just returns to the no argument action.

Here is the code I have implemented in my controller:

```
public IActionResult ChangeOneEmu()
{
    return View(new EmuItem());   
}

[HttpPut]
async public Task<IActionResult> ChangeOneEmuNew(EmuItem model)
{
    var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(model.SearchName, model);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And here is the code I have implemented in my View:

```
@model HelloEmuWebsite.Models.EmuItem

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("SubmitMe").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeOneEmuNew", "Home")',
                type: 'PUT',
                data: $('changeemuform').serialise(),
                //dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
                return false;
        });
   }); 
</script>

<form method="put" id="SubmitMe">

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SearchName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Age)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Weight)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Weight)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" id="SubmitMe" ; />
    </form>
```

And just in case, here is what my actual API implementation is:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<Models.EmuItem>> Put(string id, [FromBody] Models.EmuItem ChangedEmu)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return MyEmus.ChangeEmu(id, ChangedEmu);

    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

I would love *any* help at all. I'm not sure if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how the ASP.NET CORE MVC pattern operates, or how forms operate, or how AJAX operates, or all three or none. Thank you.

Comment: does the misspelling of `serialize` have anything to do with it?

Comment: @jPhizzle No, unfortunately. It is odd though that VS didn't catch that misspelling.

Comment: How about.. returning `Ok(MyEmus.ChangeEmu(id, ChangedEmu);` instead of `return MyEmus.ChangeEmu` since your Put method is returning an `ActionResult`... and change your `ActionResult<List<Models.EmuItem>>` to just `ActionResult Put(string id...)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes in your view :

1. add `id="changeemuform "` in `<form>`

   ```
   <form method="put"  id="changeemuform">
   ```
2. put your jQuery in `@section Scripts {}` and use the correct format of `$("#id")`

   ```
   @section Scripts
   {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#SubmitMe").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("ChangeOneEmuNew", "Home")',
                  type: 'PUT',
                  data: $('#changeemuform').serialize(),
                 //dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                  }
              });
               return false;
           });
        });
     </script>
   }
   ```